# Why would NHibernate.ISession.CreateQuery return something different from CreateSQLQuery when CacheMode=Ignore?

Tags: c#, nhibernate

This is a pretty simple question but I'm baffled by it. In the immediate window of Visual Studio, I see this:

```
session.CacheMode
Ignore

session.CreateQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Protein").List()
Count = 1
    [0]: 0

session.CreateSQLQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Protein").List()
Count = 1
    [0]: 6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be several causes for something like this, check your mappings for the following:

- A `<class>` mapping with a `where` filter.
- A `<discriminator>` with `force="true"` attribute.
- A `<join>` mapping that doesn't match on one side and isn't specified as `optional="true"`.
- A custom `<loader query-ref="...">` for the entity.
- A `<filter>` on the entity that has been enabled through `session.EnableFilter`.
- The class `Protein` isn't mapped to the `Protein` table.
- You could have 2 tables named `Protein` in different schemas, so NHibernate is querying `foo.Protein` but your sql is querying `dbo.Protein`.

After that it starts to get more esoteric such as using custom dialects, entity tuplizers, etc.

One simple way to see what is going on is to look at the SQL being issued, you can do this by:

- Setting `<property name="show_sql" value="true"/>` and watching the console/logger.
- Using a profiling tool for your server (e.g. SQL Server Profiler for MSSQL).
- Using [NHibernate Profiler](http://nhprof.com)

Comment: It was the join mapping not being optional. I didn't realize optional was the difference between inner join and left outer join. I even read the docs on it but didn't comprehend "will always use an outer join to retrieve the properties." Thanks!